# Navigate to different page in Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Code before migration:(In calssic sites):

AppsScript1(Source page):

It has many requests with req number,key and project no,proj key.
When user clicks on particular request it redirects to another page
which is AppsScript2(Response Page) .

So my index.html has the following code to redirect:

```
    var CRABLinkAPPROVE="https://sites.google.com/a/abc.com/crab/2020/approvearequest";
     var CRABLinkAPPROVErequest = CRABLinkAPPROVE + + "?Req=" + 
    Reqval + "&RKey=" + RKeyval + "&Lev=" + LevVal + "&Type=approve";

     <td style="background-color:#ff5722; color:white;">
    <a href="<?= CRABLinkAPPROVErequest ?>" target="_blank" 
    style="color:white; text-decoration: none;">REPLY</a></td>
```

So it was redirecting to Response page and shows that particular request details.

Response page Code.gs file to assign parameter values:

```
function doGet(e) {
       
  
       var Proj = e.parameter.Proj;
       var Key = e.parameter.Key;
       var Req = Number(e.parameter.Req);
       var RKey = e.parameter.RKey;
       var Level = Number(e.parameter.Lev);
}
```

In Response page I was able to get values of Req,Proj etc.

After migration to new google sites the above code is not working. So tried the below code in index.html.

Index.html:

```
 var CRABLinkAPPROVErequest = CRABLinkAPPROVE + + "?Req=" + Reqval + "&RKey=" + RKeyval + "&Lev=" + LevVal + "&Type=approve";
<td style="background-color:#ff5722; color:white;">
<a href="<?= CRABLinkAPPROVErequest ?>" target="_blank" >REPLY</a></td>
```

Note: "ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()" returns always the request page url

Code.gs file in response page:

```
function doGet(e) {
 var Proj = e.parameter.Proj;
       var Key = e.parameter.Key;
      var Req = Number(e.parameter.Req);
      var RKey = e.parameter.RKey;
       var Level = Number(e.parameter.Lev); 

}
```

Here e.parameter.Proj, e.parameter.Key all parameters are returning null

Comment: Hi. I sorry I cannot fully understood the scenario. Can you share the sample code? I cannot access the link you provided

Comment: @RonM Edited, please have a look. Thank you

Comment: Found an existing bug raised for this issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36757261)